# How do I get image hyperlink in text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, images, hyperlink

I have images with hyperlinks (copied from internet). I need to convert those hidden hyperlinks to URL in another row.

How do I do that?

Comment: Post a sample file and explain in context. What do you have where?? Hyperlinks on what? Have you copied web page content and pasted it into Excel as html? And now you want to extract the URLs for the images? Please understand that we cannot see your screen. You really, really need to explain properly what you need.

Comment: You can find file [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=56E60498F14AA80D!3514&authkey=!AC9WnWopULqkpmQ&ithint=file%2cxlsx). I need those images hyperlink's to the Product images row.

Comment: Sorry about this but I'd never used Excel online and I was taking a look at how it works and have deleted one of your columns. I assumed the data wouldn't get saved but it seemed to for some reason.

Comment: Save it on your computer and you can use regular excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not given us much information on **HOW** you want to accomplish this, so here is the basic functional way to do it.

1. Right click the image, select `Edit Hyperlink`
2. Select the `URL` in the `Address` box

[image]

3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to copy it
4. Close the window
5. Select the cell you want to paste the hyperlink
6. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to paste it

[image]

More automated ways to do this can be accomplished, but it requires knowledge of advanced features within Excel to use VBA. We don't know what your experience level is and you've not explained what you've tried or done on your own.

---

To automate this using VBA, add the below code to the VBA explorer in `Sheet1`.

You can get to the VBA window by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.

[image]

**Code:**

```
Sub GetImangeHyperlinks()

Dim shp As Shape
Dim sTemp As String

For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    sTemp = ""
    On Error Resume Next 'go to next shape if no hyperlink
    sTemp = shp.Hyperlink.Address
    On Error GoTo 0
    If sTemp <> "" Then
        'activate the cell the image is in    
        shp.TopLeftCell.Activate
        'paste down one row and back one column
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value = sTemp 
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

To run the code, place your cursor by the word `Sub`, at the beginning of the code, then press <kbd>F5</kbd>. It should run pretty quickly and the results should look like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is what I mean, but I need automated version. There is 1000+ of pictures in my original file. You can tell me and I try.

Comment: Are you familiar with VBA?

Comment: I think I can handle it

Comment: Added VBA instructions.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer is acceptable, please indicate as such with a check-mark under the vote count. That lets readers know there is an acceptable answer available when searching.